# Sort n files of "words" (8 random letters) in lexicographic order, and put it in an output.txt file

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm given *n* files, for example 3 files, with around 400000 words of eight "random" letters, ex. `aaabcdfe`. Each file is in lexicographic order and I'm supposed to merge all files in a sorted and lexicographic order to an output file (no duplicates).
I know how to get them from the file to an array and vice versa. My main problem is the space (around 32MB). I'm trying to divide the files into small chunks (maybe 60000 words, 20k from each file and then merge them together) but I'm really not sure on how to do it. Imagine I have an array sorted as I want with around 30k words, where do I go from there? Should I put them in a new file or the output file. Should I just merge them together without using arrays? Another problem is I can only write one file to the output, because if I write one file and then another the second overwrites all of the first and now I'm left with only the second file in the output. I thought about a priority queue but have not made any progress so far.
I'm still learning as this is all new to me, so sorry if this is a bit noobish. Just looking for tips from experienced people on this sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

100-200MB of data is not that much nowadays for a modern computer, so maybe a file merge and Array.Sort() will do the trick for you in many cases.

However, if the number of entries or files increases dramatically,  maybe you could choose a safer algorithm, for instance, by grouping the entries by the initial letter. You can load all the words starting by "A" or "a" from all your files into a List, then sort the list (`yourList.Sort()`), then write it to the output file. Then again, go for letter "B"/"b", and so on.

By grouping by the first letter (or first 2 letters if needed), you make sure that the sorting done at any point will not be modified by subsequent entry loads.

**EDIT**. In pseudocode it would be something like:

```cs
  char[] myLetters = ['a','b','c','d',...];

// open a read connection to all involved files and store its read pointer in and array called myLetters

// create a file and open a write connection

outputFile = File.Open(filename,"Write");

 foreach(char lett in myLetters)
 {
   List myCurrentLetterEntriesList = new List();
   foreach(File f in allMyFiles)
   {
       string Entry = f.ReadLine();

       while(Entry.FirstLetter == lett )
       {
          myCurrentLetterEntriesList .Add( Entry );
  
          Entry = f.ReadLine();
       }

       f.Seek(-1,CurrentPosition); //to start in the last entry that was discarded

   }

    myCurrentLetterEntriesList.Sort();
 
    string previousEntry =  myCurrentLetterEntriesList[0]
    outputFile.WriteLine(previousEntry);

    for i=1:myCurrentLetterEntriesList.count-1
    {
      string entry = myCurrentLetterEntriesList[i];
      if(entry!=previousEntry )
      { 
          outputFile.WriteLine(entry);
          previousEntry=entry;
      }
     }
  }

  //Close connections to input and output files
```

Comment: But how do i write multiple files into one output file, i tried it and  the last one overwrites the previous one

Comment: nvm found out how to do it. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: No problem. I have added some pseudocode in case you need to program it

Comment: This answer entirely neglects `Each file is in lexicographic order`.

Comment: @greybeard, on the contrary, entries are read and grouped from the files in order (without search) thanks to the fact that the files are already sorted. Apart from that no more generalizations are possible as the words can be interleaved or not, repeated or not, etc. What else can you profit from the lexicographic order when you have several files with non-correlative entries lists? for sure the list of letters in the code is just a simplification and they should be extracted from the entries themselves, but it is just a pseudocode example that obviously needs refining

Comment: True enough, it would seem I didn't read the code carefully enough, for all the comments and (consistent) indentation it shows. **The *entirely* in my previous comment is entirely contrafactual.** Whether or not a self-rolled *n*-way merge or using such a "chunked"/"batched" "List.Sort()" is "better" (consumes less energy/time) depends on memory hierarchy and input properties (max. "letter batch" size, for one) more than on number of comparisons or moves (parameters of "classical" sort algorithm analysis, the cost of the latter depending strongly on implementation language, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

(`I'm really not sure on how to do it`, `where do I go from there?` this is more an issue of *program development methods and practices* (the topic of the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - off topic on stack**overflow**) and *problem solving* (not the main topic of any SE site I know of).

---

Answers helpful/correct change - what was true in the 1960ies does not necessarily carry into the current millennium, or today's wisdom to 2050:
learning questions and corresponding answers is less useful in life than in exam preparation.

- `My main problem is the space (around 32MB)`
  How do you know?
  32 MB is on the order of the "farthest level cache" of the processors of a 2020 compute server.
  400000 words of 8 letters are represented in about 3.2 MB of file more likely than not (is 400000 words *total* or *per file*?).
  In many a contemporary runtime environment, characters occupy two bytes each in memory - even for 3*400000*8 characters, that's shy of 20 MB (if converting/storing many/all *word*s at once, "per word overhead" may add up: measure).
  While I think it useful to try and spot possible problems on the go:
  **Start *simple*. Test *works as intended*. *Measure*.**
- `divide the files into [say 20 chunks each…merge them together…Imagine…] an array sorted as [specified]`
  Just did: How do you know the last word from the *next* (unread) chunk from file 2 does not need to precede the first from file 1?
  As an extreme, imagine all words in any one file starting with the same letter unique among all files, say `'n'`, `'o'`, `'t'`.

---

The *conventional answer to "this" question* seems to be

- build a *priority queue PQ* containing one record from each sequence, with an indication which sequence it comes from
- while PQ is not empty

  - replace the highest priority record *R* from PQ with the next record from the same sequence, if any, else just extract *R*
  - put out *R*, deviation from "standard problem&solution": if not equal to previous output
    (alternatively *avoid inserting duplicates into PQ*)

- I don't necessarily buy it.
I hope I'd measure if "the trivial approach": *read in the whole shebang and standard sort it* doesn't do, with the approach above next.
If and when it both don't cut it, I should look for "other" "obvious" improvements, such as trying to handle *eight letter words* as *64 bit machine words*.
That failing, I might try reading the files in batches, keeping a PQ as above of the *last/least priority word/record already read from each file*, and happily process records until putting out one equal to the highest priority record from PQ, reading another batch from it's file.